# find bug position in source code during vc debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-express, visual-c++

I created a DLL. The source codes can be compiled and linked. During running, it works normally somehow, but in certain situations it crashes. At this point, VC just shows me a window to ask me whether to Break or Continue，but it doesn't tell where the error in the code is.

My question is, is it possible to configure the VC debugging in any way so that a breakpoint is directly set at the code position where the error happened? Or how can I find the source code bug position?

P.s. I use VC Express 2010

Comment: Well, if you select 'break', doesn't it take you to the position where the error happened?

Comment: no ... I just got a window telling me "No Source Available, No symbols are loaded for any stack frame". Any idea?

Comment: Then it appears that you are running a release build, not a debug build. Have you checked this?

Comment: The crash might have occurred in third party dll with no symbols available. Choose Break, then look at call stack (it is in Debug->Windows->Call Stack). Double click on the topmost stack frame corresponding to your code.<br/>
Note that debugger might not be able to display call stack when symbols are missing.

Comment: He said that 'No symbols are loaded for any stack frame'. So the crash would have to have occurred not only in a third party dll, but also on a different thread. Unlikely.

Comment: I know for sure that the error was in the codes for my dll. The call stack loction is ntdll.dll!7c90120e().

Comment: It's possible that the bug corrupted the stack so badly that the call stacks were unrecoverable. You may have to "debug forward" by stepping through the code and finding the last statement before things blow up.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
MessageBox(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi， I just want to give an update about my problem. I found the bug in codes. It was a pointer type variable which took a un-initialized memory address. The code line in my DLL was totally correct and did not lead to any problem. But outside of my codes, a DLL which uses this variable then got a access protection error and lead to crashdown of the whole program.

I found the problem just basded on the timer value in codes. Luckily the mother program which calls my DLL can tell at wich time point this error was happened before its window totally crashed.